# Perl - Printing the next line

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I am a noob Perl user trying to get my work done ASAP so I can go home on time today :)

Basically I need to print the next line of blank lines in a text file.

The following is what I have so far. It can locate blank lines perfectly fine. Now I just have to print the next line.

```
    open (FOUT, '>>result.txt');

die "File is not available" unless (@ARGV ==1);

open (FIN, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";

@rawData=<FIN>;
$count = 0;

foreach $LineVar (@rawData)
    {
        if($_ = ~/^\s*$/)
        {
            print "blank line \n";
                    #I need something HERE!!

        }
        print "$count \n";
        $count++;
    }
close (FOUT);
close (FIN);
```

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Is it sensible to slurp the whole file into memory?  It isn't 100% necessary for the exercise shown.

Comment: It isn't even 1% necessary, even if you want to use an array.   Take a look at Tie::File (part of the core since 5.8, around 2002).

Comment: File was not that big, but definitely it wasn't good idea. I will take a look at the Tie::File :) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
open (FOUT, '>>result.txt');

die "File is not available" unless (@ARGV ==1);

open (FIN, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!\n";

$count = 0;

while(<FIN>)
{
    if($_ = ~/^\s*$/)
    {
            print "blank line \n";
            count++;
            <FIN>;
            print $_;

    }
    print "$count \n";
    $count++;
}
close (FOUT);
close (FIN);
```

- not reading the entire file into @rawData saves memory, especially in the case of large files...
- `<FIN>` as a command reads the next line into $_
- `print ;` by itself is a synonym for `print $_;` (although I went for the more explicit variant this time...

Comment: what happens with the above in the event where you have two blank lines in a row?
presumably you would want to print the line following the 2nd blank line, but this code will skip such a line, will it not?

Comment: @blackkettle: very true. If that is a requirement, then Ron/malach's solution is better.

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution :) luckily my file did not have two blanks in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on Ron Savage's solution:

```
foreach $LineVar (@rawData)
    {
        if ( $lastLineWasBlank ) 
           {
                print $LineVar;
                $lastLineWasBlank = 0;
           }
        if($LineVar  =~ /^\s*$/)
        {
                print "blank line \n";
                    #I need something HERE!!
                $lastLineWasBlank = 1;
        }
        print "$count \n";
        $count++;
    }
```

Comment: I think you want `if($LineVar =~ /^\s*$/)` since you're not using $_ in the loop, are you?

Comment: Also, do you want `0` and `1` where you have `false` and `true`? (No built-in booleans in Perl, are there?)

Comment: so if I were to use this solution, do I need to put quotations around 'true' and 'false'?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, haven't been doing Perl for quite a while

Comment: @mr.flow3r: No, you can't do it directly with 'true' and 'false', even if you quote them. (Well, unless you then test if `$flag eq 'true'` which is too wordy.) I would use 0 and 1 for simple booleans in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go like this but there's probably other ways to do it:

```
for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < @rawData ; $i++ ){
   if ( $rawData[$i] =~ /^\s*$/ ){
       print $rawData[$i + 1] ; ## plus check this is not null
   }
}
```

J.

Comment: Doesn't this just print all non blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable like $lastLineWasBlank, and set it at the end of each loop.

```
if ( $lastLineWasBlank ) 
   {
   print "blank line\n" . $LineVar;
   }
```

something like that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
sh> perl -ne 'if ($b) { print }; if ($b = !/\S/) { ++$c }; END { print $c,"\n" }'
```

Add input filename(s) to your liking.